# Extracting image from PDF to use in LaTeX document?

Tags: graphics, pdf

I need to include some graphs from a datasheet in my document, but of course I don't have the source files.
What would be the best course of action? It's mostly logarithmic scale graphs.

Comment: Hi, it would help if you could minimise the work people have to do if they want to help you. For example, we don't know what kind of datasheets you're using, what OS you're using, what kind of output you're looking for (ps, pdf, ...), and so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Alternatively you could extract the data from the graph and then recreate it in your own style. There are several programs available that digitize graphs (e.g. http://digitizer.sourceforge.net/) and in the end this is often the much nicer than a copy&paste and also avoids copyright issues.

Comment: Yes. This enables you to apply a consistent style across all the data you ripped off from different sources. I prefer another digitizing program (see `http://plotdigitizer.sourceforge.net/); the one mentioned above gave me some random crashes.

Answer (score 19):

use

```
\includegraphics[page=...,viewport=llx lly urx ury,clip]{pdf-file}
```

or run

```
pdfimages [options] <PDF-file> <image-root>
```

the first one simply inserts the `page=<no>` of your pdf and clips everything around the viewport. The second one is a Linux command, which extracts all images from a pdf file, eg

```
pdfimages -f1 -l4 <PDF-file> .
```

extracts the images of pages 1--4 into the current directory

Comment: +1: probably worth mentioning that `\includegraphics` is from the `graphicx` package

Comment: no, `\includegraphics` is from `graphics`, only the optional arguments need `graphicx` ... ;-)

Comment: Note that `pdfimages` will extract only bitmap graphics. If the graphic is a line drawing, such as a cartoon or plot, pdfimages will not find it. Also note that by default `pdfimages` writes `ppm` files. You can give it a `-j` option to make it save `jpeg` files instead.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer, Is there any way to extract line drawings from a pdf file?

Comment: `pdfimages` expects a raster image. If the "image" is actually a bit of vector art---pdfimages won't help, in which inkscape or [krop](http://arminstraub.com/software/krop) (or one of its alternatives) can be used instead.

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that you are using OS X with TeXShop and that your original file is in pdf format.

A manual solution that works if there aren't too many images to copy is as follows.

TeXShop's pdf viewer allows you to copy part of a page or image. It works even for pdf files that don't come from a tex file. All you have to do is select the region you want copied with the rectangle selection tool and drag the image to your desktop (or other folder). In TeXShop's preference pane you can select the format of the copied image (pdf, png, etc.)

Maybe other pdf viewers behave like this but since I don't use them I don't know.

Comment: This answer is gold.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux (Mint 17) a (semiautomatic) trick that worked for me is, first extract the page with the desired vector figure using pdftk:

```
 pdftk book.pdf cat 51 output page.pdf
```

in this case, the page 51 from the file **book.pdf** is extracted into the file **page.pdf** .

Then using Inkscape, it is possible to open the file page.pdf, select the figure, copy and paste it in a new window, then save it as a new pdf (as a vector image), ready to be included in LaTeX!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, it is possible to use a PDF printer in order to print a current view in a PDF file and use a paper format that corresponds to the dimensions. In this way, vector graphics are preserved. This is kind of a dirty trick, but it works for me...

Answer (score 1):

One way to extract data if it is available in the PDF as vector graphics is to use Adobe Acrobat:

1. Enter editing mode by using the tool "Edit PDF" under Tools.
2. Select all the points/shapes/markers you want to copy
3. Select "Edit Using..." in the right sidebar and select your text editor [image: Objects panel]
4. The coordinates of the markers should be available in the text (in centimeters most probably), so find out the format of one marker and extract all the coordinates. Regular expressions can help.
5. Scale and convert the coordinates into the original values by comparing points to the actual axes in the graph.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

I use Adobe Acrobat to select regions and save images to `.bmp`.
Then I convert them to `.eps` with a sam2p utility, using `.bat` file for batch processing.

[sam2p project on google code](http://code.google.com/p/sam2p/)

`.bat` file code:

```
REM Created by M.M.J. Jorritsma. 2011-09-21, Enschede, The Netherlands
@SET /P INPUT=[Type the extension of the images to be batch-converted. example: jpg]
@SET /P OUTPUT=[Type the extension of the target image format. example: eps]
@ECHO Now converting from "%INPUT%" to "%OUTPUT%".
@SET /P CONTINUE=[Continue? [Y/N]]
@if /I %CONTINUE%==Y (
    @for /R %%i In (*.%INPUT%) DO @(
    @cls
    @echo sam2p %%~ni.%INPUT% %%~ni.%OUTPUT%
    sam2p %%~ni.%INPUT% %%~ni.%OUTPUT%
    )
)
```

Comment: This is potentially messy. If the image you're copying, which is likely to be a vector graphic if it is a plot, is saved to bitmap before putting it into an `eps` container then the resultant `eps` is not a vector graphic. This typically results in low quality images (looks bad) or large files (pdf readers may get choppy when you scroll and the document that it is put in will be large). In short, one should avoid turning a vector graphic into a raster graphic if it is to be placed in another vector graphic later.

Comment: Thanks for comment, @MarkS.Everitt! Haven't thought about it. In my case there were raster images.