# Are there any commands for extracting pictures (not only bitmap graphics but also line drawings) from a pdf file?

Tags: graphics, pdf

I know that `pdfimages` can extract bitmap graphics from a pdf file.

But what if the embedded image is some line drawings, e.g., an image generated by some TikZ code in LaTeX?

Assumption: the pdf file is a certain scientific paper. It could contain multi figures on one page. (Sorry that I did not mention this.)

**EDIT**

I just need the high quality picture. 
It seems the picture is generated by some tikz commands (it's a vector picture for sure).

Well, it's nice to know the commands for generating that picture, but I did not expect that would be possible.

**EDIT2**

I'm using the `trim` & `clip`, options of `\includegraphics` now, but still looking forward to some automatic extraction commands.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics[trim = 15mm 113mm 110mm 130mm, clip]{a-single-page-pdf-file}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT3**

Add a ruler, just to make it easier

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    %\includegraphics[trim = 1.5cm 11.3cm 11cm 13cm, clip]{single-page-pdf}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{single-page-pdf}};
        % A4 paper size: 21.0 × 29.7
        \draw[help lines,xstep=1,ystep=1] (0,0) grid (21,29.7);
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,21} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x,0) {\x}; }
        \foreach \y in {0,1,...,29.7} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y) {\y}; }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So what you actually want is the `TikZ` code of the picture in the PDF?

Comment: You cannot extract the TikZ information. You can of course extract the vector graphics produced, if that is what you want.

Comment: I just need the high quality picture. Or should I just use trim option to include that pdf file?

Comment: Maybe this question is what you're looking for: [How can I use TikZ to make standalone graphics?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51757)

Comment: @AlanMunn Actually I want to do the inverse.

Comment: Depending on your OS there should be ways of doing this manually. For example in Mac Preview, I can select text or image and crop to a size and resave as a PDF or other image format.

Comment: Are all your images single page PDFs?

Comment: @AlanMunn,Thank you. Yes, it's single page (accually I print "current page" to another pdf file.). (I'm using Fedora 18. Maybe inkscape or xpdf will do this pdf-editing job?! I have not tried.)

Comment: As you are not asking about TiKz, But general graphics extraction, have retagged your question. I suggest to make that also explicit in the title and body of the question.

Comment: @Daniel, I just changed the title, and also some part in the body according one comments on this page (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40658/extracting-image-from-pdf-to-use-in-latex-document?rq=1). But I'm not sure whether it's proper to use the term "bitmap graphics" and "line drawing" here. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, Inkscape can be used to extract Vector art from a pdf.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you want, because it's unclear how much automation will be of use to you.  In this answer, I'll first generate a PDF document that has one TikZ image on each page (I know you don't need to know how to do that, but it will make the whole process a self-contained example for others.)  Then I'll use the [`pdftk` utility](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) to split each page into a single PDF file.  I'll then use the `pdfcrop` utility from within the LaTeX document to crop each page and then use `\includegraphics` to include it. So the final result will be a single page with each of the individual images included and automatically cropped.

To make this solution work, you need to compile the second document with `\write18` enabled.

### Generate some images

Filename: *repeat-circles.tex*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [red,fill,text={white},font={\bfseries\Huge}, circle, minimum width=\x cm ] {\x};
\end{tikzpicture}
\clearpage
}
\end{document}
```

This will create a file with 5 circles of different sizes, each on its own page.

### Split the file with pdftk

Now we use `pdftk` to split the file into 5 separate pages:

`% pdftk repeat-circles.pdf burst`

By default this will create one file for each page with filenames `pg_<nnnn>.pdf`.

If you are generating the single pages manually, you will not need this step.

### Crop and include each file as in image into another document

Now we create a LaTeX document which will take each of these individual pages, crop the image and include each one using `\includegraphics`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}
{
\immediate\write18{pdfcrop pg_000\x.pdf}
\includegraphics{pg_000\x-crop.pdf}
}
\end{document}
```

The final output of this document is:

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what if the figure is surrounded by some text and other figures? (there is some text and could be several figures on one single page of a paper.)

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that automatically. Or at least, I know of no way to do this.